# Trying to ID these FinFETs

Tags: identification

I'm trying to ID this FET, but can't seem to find anything.
The logo looks like "FCE"
It says B6066 M300AM

How can I ID these guys in the future?

[image: pcb with fets to ID]

Comment: A small nit - these are likely not FinFETs, but power FETs.

Comment: It will help to know what type of device, instrument or whatever this board came out of.  Is there a reason you suspect these are FinFETs?  There's generally not a lot of great ways (that I've found) for finding surface mount components, it's generally a slog of googling different things until you start getting more towards what you need.

I don't recognize the logo, but finding that out and whatever SMD package that is would probably go a long way.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @nanofarad , I'm new to all this.

Comment: @snowmanemperor there's are on a Fysetc tmc5160 stepstick stepper motor driver. They're fets of some sort, still learning what is what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [Huashuo Semiconductor](http://www.hs-semi.cn/product.asp) [HSBB6066](http://www.hs-semi.cn/Uploadfiles/20210901163937074.pdf) n-channel MOSFETs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was there something in particular that you used to find these?  Or did you possibly recognize the logo or FET itself?

Comment: @snowmanemperor “B6066” mosfet gives a first hit depending on which search engine you use.

Comment: Thank you very much!!